# Is optimization in Remix worth the risk of bugs?

Tags: remix, opcode

Is the future gas savings for users worth the risk of bugs? In other words, is optimization worth it when launching a token using Remix?

Tether has had 112 million transfers...https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7

Does that mean Tether should have optimized itself for 112 million runs or more?

Would Tether even want to risk optimization? Does Tether reach a point where it becomes completely unoptimized?

**What is the least buggy way of launching my token? I want my token to have the least bugs as possible even if gas costs are higher. Should I uncheck optimization in that case?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in optimization should never introduce any dangerous bugs. I haven't heard of any such issues with it, ever.

Also, there's no need to set the optimization to 112 million. I'm really not familiar with all the things the optimization does, but most likely the basic value of *200* is the highest you ever need. It should basically really only be the matter of choosing between these three options: 1) no optimization 2) optimization for very low amount of calls (using value *1*, for example) - makes deployment cheaper 3) optimization for high amount of calls with *200* - makes calls cheaper

Comment: https://blog.ethereum.org/2017/05/03/solidity-optimizer-bug/ Also would 200 be enough for Tether hypothetically?

Comment: Well, as with any code, bugs do occur, but I haven't heard of any which would cause real issues. As I said, I'm not familiar with the optimization process, so can't really say for sure, but my guess is that 200 would produce exactly the same result as 112 million.